# How to display 0 in count?

Tags: sqlite

How can I display 0 if there is no qualification matching?

My current query is:

```
select s.sname, count(*) as number
from sailor s, boat b
where s.rating >= b.rating
group by s.sname
order by number desc;
```

And the result I got is:

```
a  3
b  3
c  2
```

However, it is not really what I am trying to achieve. I would like to display the result like this:

```
a 3
b 3
c 2
d 0
e 0
```

I try to change count(*) to isnull(count(*), 0) or coalesce(count(*), 0) but it doesnt correct in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE sailor (
    sname   character varying primary key,
    rating  integer
);

create table boat (
    bname   character varying primary key,
    color   character varying,
    rating  integer
);
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of sailor and boat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
select s.sname,(select count(*) 
from boat b
where s.rating >= b.rating
) t
from sailor s
order by t desc;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/752a7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an inner join, which returns only rows when data in both tables matches.

To return sailors without any matching boat, use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join):

```
select s.sname, count(*) as number
from sailor s
left join boat b on s.rating >= b.rating
group by s.sname
order by number desc;
```